# Make Tensorflow predictions on time series data? (Regression Model)

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning

I've tried this same exercise with a shallow Machine Learning algorithm (Ridge Regression), but I wanted to give a Neural Network a try.

I have access to raw sensor data in the following format. (+100k rows)

```
Timestamp    OilPressure     OilTemperature     RPM     FilterRestriction
0001         145             90                 1100    15
0002         140             92                 1100    15
0003         134             93                 1123    16
0004         143             91                 1135    14
```

The label for this exercise is OilPressure, and I've trained the following model on it.

```
model = keras.Sequential([
   layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
   layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
   layers.Dense(1)
])
```

I split my original data set 25% and 75%, since I want to train and test the model on the original 25% an use that as the baseline for my "healthy" equipment. So I sorted the data set ascending by date and split it accordingly.

That 25% was further randomly split 80%/20% for train test.

The resulting model gives me a MSE of 3 PSI roughly...

What I would like to do now is populate the original dataframe with another column where I can compare the actual OilPressure to the predicted OilPressure. The predictions will be generated by the model trained off the 25% but will apply to the 85% that wasn't trained or tested.

I was thinking of applying a lambda function but I'm not sure if that would work, can I define some other sort of function that takes in OilTemperature, RPM and FilterRestriction, passes it to my model and spits out a PredictedOilPressure?

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
Timestamp    OilPressure     OilTemperature     RPM     FilterRestriction    PredictedOilPressure
1000         139             89                 1203    11                   141
1001         142             89                 1109    10                   142
1002         146             87                 1177    10                   147
1003         143             84                 1205    12                   144
```

Comment: Why not just predict the whole dataset and then simply add the predictions as a new column in the existing dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Create a pandas dataframe for every record you would like to make predictions on. (X_features) and then just use the model.predict() function in order to make the predictions. save the results as a column in the dataset.

```
dataset['PredictedOilPressure'] = model.predict(X_features)
```